# Не видит переменную во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Я недавно написал свой API сервер на node+express и теперь пытаюсь присоединить его к фронт-енду при помощи `axios` но я получил вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мой код:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="title"><span>Fetured Items</span><br>
    <span>Shop for items based on what we featured in this week</span></p>
    <div v-if="products && products.length" class="content">
      <content-item v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"
      v-bind:name="product.name"
      v-bind:price="product.price"
       v-bind:srcToProdImage = "'localhost:8081/' + product.productImage" ></content-item>
    </div>
    <p class="cont-btn">
      <button class="btn">Browse All Product <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Content_item from './Content-item';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data:{
    products,
    errors
  },
  created(){
    axios.get('localhost:8081/products')
    .then((result) => {
      this.products = result.data.products
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.errors.push(err)
    });
  },
  components: {
    'content-item' : Content_item
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  span:first-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  span:last-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #9f9f9f;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
.cont-btn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn{
  padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;
  background-color: #f16d7f;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Подскажите как исправить саму ошибку и почему она появилась.Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: где объявлена переменная используемая тут: `data:{
    products,
    errors
  },`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] и вставьте текст ошибок в виде _текста_, чтобы впоследствии возможно было бы легко его найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вид

```
{
    products,
    errors
}
```

Называется [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2). И в данном случае определение свойства `data` эквивалентно следующему:

```
data: {
    products: products,
    errors: errors
}
```

Отсюда видно, что используются две переменные `products` и `error`, значения которых присваиваются одноименным полям. Так как ни одной из переменных нет и возникает указанная ошибка.

Для решения поля нужно просто инициализировать, например:

```
data: {
    products: [], // по умолчанию пустой массив
    errors: [], // по умолчанию пустой массив
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Ошибка пропала но наплодились новые))